# Movie about gene therapy and genetics-based jobs

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, genetic-engineering

I saw a movie several years ago and I have not been able to find it since.

It was about a dystopian society where parents could modify the genes of their children before birth.

Some individuals, including the protagonist, had not had this done, and so had a somewhat inferior genetic makeup.

Jobs are based on the results of genetic tests, and the protagonist, a male, was slated for a less than ideal job. In the movie, he fakes his identity and has major surgery to make him a little taller to match his ID. He is trying to get his dream job (astronaut?).

The only other parts I remember are

- the protagonist, to keep up the ruse, managing to run on a treadmill faster than his  genetic limit
- a very suspicious character pulling the protagonist's DNA from a hair left in a comb

Comment: It's not that he ran faster, but that he ran steadily with ease. The immediately following scene is him calmly opening the locker room door and collapsing and gasping for breath, which is something a genetically modified individual would not have to do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This sounds a lot (aka exactly) like [Gattaca](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119177/).

- Dystopian society - check
- Male protagonist is not genetically modified - check
- Jobs based on genetic tests, which the protagonist
  fakes - check
- major surgery to be taller - check
- protagonist trying to be astronaut - check
- treadmill scene - check
- DNA from hair left in comb - check

[image]

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: fantastic movie, by the way. AND it's on Netflix :)

Comment: The name is entirely composed of letters matching the bases of DNA... G, A, T, C.

Comment: @dev_feed, but only on DVD :(